# Unable to set image in NSImageView subclass

Tags: swift, nsimageview

I have a very basic NSImageView Sub Class, and adding it via a Custom View item in the Interface Builder from XCode:

```
class DropView:NSImageView {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        print("init") --> Displayed
        self.image=NSImage(named: "DropImage")
    }
}
```

However my DropImage (which returns a non-nil element) is not displayed on the ImageView. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: What is the "Custom View item" and how is the image view added? Or is the image view a "Custom View" in IB with class `DropView`? That's not going to work, the custom view doesn't have an image cell.

Comment: Sorry for not having been clear. The custom view is a swift file containing the DropView class (code published). Then from IB I am adding an element called Custom View and setting as view type DropView. I want the code to display an asset image (and do other things, hence the need for a custom class).

Answer (score 0):

A Custom View in IB is just a `NSView`. `NSImageView` is a subclass of `NSControl` and needs a cell to function. Replace the Custom View by an Image View and change the class.